# When i execute batch file from .php how can i actually open Windows Command Line in the foreground and see the entire process

Tags: php, batch-file

I am going crazy trying to find how how i can start batch file from PHP script in the foreground. By Foreground i mean, to actually start cmd Windows and see the entire process. I don't even need to pass anything to this batch file, just simulate as if you have double-clicked on the batch file from php webpage. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
system("cmd /c [path to file]");
?>
```

OR try

```
<?php
exec("[path to file]");
?>
```